# Can I exit to India (Indian citizen) directly from Qatar (VISA on Arrival) & an UAE resident

Tags: indian-citizens, uae, qatar

Can I exit to India (Indian citizen) directly from Qatar (return journey) (VISA on Arrival at Qatar)) & an UAE resident. Also can I arrive to Doha from India on (VISA ON ARRIVAl) as I  am an UAE resident VISA holder.

Comment: I suppose the answer is "yes" -- why would you think either trip would pose a problem?

Comment: There are several airlines that operate direct flights between Doha and a number of destinations in India. So yes, it is quite possible to travel directly between the two countries. However, Qatar's visa-on-arrival scheme does not appear to be available for Indian citizens.